# How to calculate average rating of each products in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have `products` index with following mapping:

```
{
  "products" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "name":{
          "type": "text"
        }, 
        "price" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "product_review_rel" : {
          "type" : "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals" : true,
          "relations" : {
            "product" : "review"
          }
        },
        "rate" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This index contains products and reviews, as you can see at `product_review_rel` field.
Products contain name, price, ... fields.
Reviews contain rate, ... fields.

I want to get average rating of each products. How to do that?
Another question, is it possible to return average rating from products returned by the following query in the same request:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "translations",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "kem chống nắng",
          "fields": [
            "name"
          ],
          "analyzer":"vi_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1: Composite aggregation**

````
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "translations",
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "kem chống nắng",
          "fields": [
            "translations.name",
            "translations.description"
          ],
          "analyzer": "vi_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "products": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "_id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "reviews": {
          "children": {
            "type": "review"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "rating": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "rate"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Use terms aggregation with average sub aggregation

Comment: @jaspreetchahal all right, I got your idea. Can you help me answer the second question?

Comment: Aggregation gets applied on result of query . So documents and aggregation you will get in same query

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Thanks, to make it more clear, for example, the query returns 10/14 products (total = 14, size = 10), order by their score. How to aggregate with only these 10 products.

Comment: For pagination add terms and average aggregation under composite aggregation. Problem with composite aggregation is you can only paginate sequentially i.e you cannot jump from page 1 to 3.

Comment: @jaspreetchahal can you give me some example code? I tried with composite aggregation but it doesn't work, I think I have to order average aggregation by score. You can check my update.